# Project Euler #368 (Math Formula)

Tags: ruby, math, calculus

In Project Euler, [a problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=368) asks me to write a program to find the convergence value of 20 terms from the Harmonic sequence:

```
1/111, 1/222, 1/333, 1/444, 1/555, 1/666, 1/777, 1/888, 1/999, 1/1000, 1/1110, 1/1111, 1/1112, 1/1113, 1/1114, 1/1115, 1/1116, 1/1117, 1/1118, and 1/1119
```

I want to write the program myself to solve the problem, however, not having dealt with Calc II, I had to read up on Divergence/Convergence.  All the explanations deal with series that can be represented by a formula.  This series, as far as I can tell, cannot.

So, the question is:

Is there a formula to represent this series or is there a method for finding the convergence of this series without a formula?

Comment: belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com
Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software developmen

Comment: Note that the actual task is different than you stated. You need to find a convergence of harmonic series from which those 20 elements are removed.

Comment: Outstanding, I had misread the phrase "Find the value the series converges to" as pertaining to the 20 terms removed, not the remaining series without the 20 terms.  Based on that, I found an article called "SUMMING CURIOUS, SLOWLY CONVERGENT, HARMONIC
SUBSERIES" by THOMAS SCHMELZER AND ROBERT BAILLIE which looks to solve my problem.  Thanks Mchl

Comment: Just remember, that you might actually need to remove even more terms if you go beyond 1200 initial terms. You need to give answer to 10 decimal places, so you need to keep summing, until the difference is below 10^(-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the problem carefully you will notice that there is in fact a formula. The sequence you're dealing with is a harmonic series, from which terms having 3 or more equal consecutive digits have been removed. Brute force approach here would be to sum all terms of harmonic series omitting those specified until required precision is reached. Ruby with its `Rational` class seems really fine candidate to that.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anybody considers brute-forcing it:

The brute force approach will here, as in most high-numbered Project Euler problems, not finish within reasonable time.

Suppose your computer could handle 10<sup>9</sup> numbers per second (it can handle far fewer, actually). To sum the valid terms up to 10<sup>n</sup> for `n > 9` would take about 10<sup>n-9</sup> seconds.

How far would you have to go to determine the sum to ten places after the decimal point?

Far enough that the sum of all larger valid terms is less than 10<sup>-10</sup>. Will 10<sup>12</sup> be far enough? No. Consider the next thousand numbers from

```
1001001001001
```

The invalid numbers among them are

```
1001001001110
1001001001111
1001001001112
...
1001001001119
1001001001222
1001001001333
1001001001444
...
1001001001999
1001001002000
```

Those are 19, so there are 981 valid numbers and the corresponding sum is larger than 981/1001001002000, which is more than 9*10<sup>-10</sup>. A bit of further reasoning along those lines shows that you would have to brute force much higher than 10<sup>15</sup> - in fact, you would have to go beyond 10<sup>2000</sup> before the sum of the remaining valid terms becomes less than 10<sup>-10</sup>.

A brute force started at the beginning of the universe would not be even remotely near a reliable answer yet.

Comment: And that's what Project Euler is all about :) +1

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thomas Schmelzer here...

Answer (score 0):

The naive and brute force approach for this problem would be to write a loop iterating over the denominator of the series and adding the inverse of the denominator to a overall sum given it is not excluded by the restrictions stated in the problem description.

The outline would be similar to this:

```
for i in (1..1200)
  if is_valid(i) then
    sum += 1.0 / i
  end
end

def is_valid(_i)
  # implement the check here. hint: use modulo operator ;-)
end
```